# VSCode doesn't show python script error output

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using Python3 with Visual Studio Code ([Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python) installed) within Ubuntu 16.04.
I have some basic script written:

```
def mainMethod():

    what()   
    #connectToDevice()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainMethod()
```

When I debug this in Visual Studio Code by hitting F5 I can't see any output with the error in Debug Console:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main.py", line 9, in 
>       mainMethod()
>     File "main.py", line 5, in mainMethod
>       what()
>   NameError: name 'what' is not defined

If I run `python3 main.py` in console the output appears.

How can I see those errors in VSCode and avoid switching back and forth between it and console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Feb 2018 update to VS Code this issue appears to be entirely resolved. So you don't need to make any changes to the default config, becuase the integrated debug terminal is finally printing errors when they occur.

Answer (score 4):

I still can't see the output in `Debug Console` all the time but I can see it in the `Integrated Terminal` by setting this option in `launch.json` file of VSCode. The file looks like this:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python virtual env",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.py",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ],
        "pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/env/bin/python3"
    }
]
}
```

The core line is `"console": "integratedTerminal"`. Also please note that this configuration is using the interpreter from the Virtual Environment folder and the file which starts is always `main.py` instead of the default option which runs the file from the active editor.

EDIT: it seems that later versions solved this problem so above workaround doesn't apply anymore

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz I didn't pursue any other way besides the one above.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better way, for me, is to just add "console": "externalTerminal" rather than internalTerminal. That opens a new terminal when debugging, but it's a clearer one and it closes almost automatically.

Comment: Does that open a truly external terminal (like you would do by running a "cmd" window process)?

Comment: No it's tied to the debugging instance. Just a display output.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in my case was the Python Linter didn't show the errors.

My mistake was, that **I open the VS Code when a VirtualEnv was active**. Whit the command

> code .

To fixed I close VS Code, delete de .vs folder, deactivate de VirtualEnv, then open VS Code and then open VirtualEnv.

And done!, problem solve. Other solution in my case would be install the linter (if I remember right, pylint is the default linter for vscode).